# Ellipse in a rectangle

Tags: conic-sections

What is the equation for an ellipse (or rather, family of ellipses) which has as its tangents the lines forming the following rectangle?

$$x=\pm a, y=\pm b\;\; (a,b>0)$$

This question is a modification/extension of [Equation of ellipse tangent to axes](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/2303661).

Comment: Consider the family of rhombuses that are tangent to the unit circle at 4 edges. Then a linear transformation brings the rhombuses to the rectangle and the unit circle to the family of ellipses inside the rectangle at 4 edges. It's easy to see why this would give ALL such ellipses inside the rectangle.

Comment: @MaudPieTheRocktorate - Interesting concept. Would you care to elaborate and expand this into a full answer?

Answer (score 2):

Consider the family of rhombuses that are tangent to the unit circle at 4 edges. Then a linear transformation brings the rhombuses to the rectangle and the unit circle to the family of ellipses inside the rectangle at 4 edges.

Explicitly, draw a rhombus such that it's tangent to the unit circle at 4 edges, and two edges are parallel to x-axis, and the other two edges make an angle $2\theta$ with the x-axis. Then by a shearing along the x-axis, then a scaling along the x-axis and y-axis, you can transform the rhombus to the rectangle you gave.

Using this method, we get the family of ellipses 
$$\frac{x^2}{a^2\sin^2{(2\theta)}}+\frac{y^2}{b^2\sin^2{(2\theta)}}+\frac{2\cos{(2\theta)}xy}{ab\sin^2{(2\theta)}}=1$$
with $0<\theta<\pi/2$

It's easy to see why this would give ALL such ellipses inside the rectangle.

BTW you can check that when $\theta = \pi/4$, the ellipse is just $x^2/a^2+y^2/b^2=1$, the most obvious one. When $\theta = 0$, it degenerates to a diagonal, and when $\theta = \pi/2$, it degenerates to the other diagonal.

Comment: Nice solution. (+1)

Answer (score 1):

By exploiting the affine map $(x,y)\mapsto\left(\frac{x}{a},\frac{y}{b}\right)$ the question boils down to finding the family of ellipses inscribed in a square with vertices at $(\pm 1,\pm 1)$. In a ellipse the line joining the midpoints of parallel chords always go through the center. Additionally, the [orthoptic curve](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Orthoptic_(geometry)) of an ellipse is the [director circle](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Director_circle). It follows that all the ellipses that are tangent to the sides of the previous square fulfill $a^2+b^2=2$, are centered at the origin and are symmetric with respect to the diagonals of the square.

[image]

Here it is a straightedge-and-compass construction.

1. Take some point $P$ on the perimeter of the square and by reflecting it
    with respect to the center and the diagonals of the square construct the rectangle $PQRS$;
2. Consider the tangents at $P,Q,R,S$ at the circumcircle of $PQRS$;
3. Two intersections of such tangents are the vertices of the inscribed ellipse through $P$,
    that is simple to draw.

Comment: Very impressive construction! (+1)

Answer (score 0):

This solution is inspired by the [Lissajous diagram](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Lissajous_curve).

Consider two signal inputs $x, y$ which are out of phase, with magnitudes $a,b$ respectively, fed into an oscilloscope.

The resulting Lissajous diagram will be a tilted ellipse with tangents $x=\pm a, y=\pm b$ and parametric equations
$$\begin{cases}
x=a\sin(t+u)\\
y=b\cos(t+v)\end{cases}$$
with $t$ being the parameter.

Eliminating* $t$ gives the Cartesian form as follows:

$$\color{red}{\frac {x^2}{a^2}+\frac{y^2}{b^2}-\frac {2xy}{ab}\sin(u-v)=\cos^2(u-v)}$$

which is the equation of the family of ellipses with tangents $x=\pm a, y=\pm b$.

Alternatively, this can be stated using a variable $m$ in place of $\sin(u-v)$ where $|m|\le 1$, i.e. 
$$\color{red} 
{ \frac {x^2}{a^2}+\frac {y^2}{b^2}-\frac {2mxy}{ab}=1-m^2\qquad (|m|\le 1)}\\
$$

The tangent points are $\pm(am,b), \pm(a,bm)$.

See desmos implementation [here](https://www.desmos.com/calculator/1gwixpvfn8).

[image]

---

$\color{lightgrey}{\text{*Detailed derivation below:}}$
$$\color{lightgrey}{
\begin{align}
t=\overbrace{\sin^{-1}\left(\frac xa\right)}^\alpha-u&=
\overbrace{\cos^{-1}\left(\frac yb\right)}^\beta-v\\
\alpha-\beta&=u-v\\
\sin(\alpha-\beta)&=\sin(u-v)\\
\sin\alpha\cos\beta-\cos\alpha\sin\beta&=\sin(u-v)\\
\frac xa\cdot \frac yb-\sqrt{\left(1-\frac {x^2}{a^2}\right)}
\cdot \sqrt{\left(1-\frac {y^2}{b^2}\right)}&=\sin(u-v)\\
xy-ab\sin(u-v)&=\sqrt{(a^2-x^2)(b^2-y^2)}\\
x^2y^2-2abxy\sin(u-v)+a^2b^2\sin^2(u-v)&=(a^2-x^2)(b^2-y^2)\\
&=a^2b^2-b^2x^2-a^2y^2+x^2y^2\\
b^2x^2+a^2y^2-2abxy\sin(u-v)-a^2b^2(1-\sin^2(u-v))&=0\\
b^2x^2+a^2y^2-2abxy\sin(u-v)-a^2b^2\cos^2(u-v)&=0\\
\frac {x^2}{a^2}+\frac{y^2}{b^2}-\frac {2xy}{ab}\sin(u-v)&=\cos^2(u-v)
\end{align}}$$

Answer (score 0):

Here's a purely algebraic approach without any use of trigonometric functions.

By symmetry, the center of the ellipse is at the origin, so its
equation is just
$$
Ax^2 + Bxy + Cy^2 = 1
$$
with $A>0,$ $C>0,$ and $B^2 < 4AC.$
The tangents at $y = \pm b$ will occur at values of $y$ for which the
quadratic equation in $x,$ $Ax^2 + Bxy + Cy^2 - 1 = 0,$
has a double root.
This occurs when 
$$(By)^2 - 4A(Cy^2 - 1) = 0,$$
that is, at
$$
y^2 = \frac{4A}{4AC - B^2}.
$$
For similar reasons, the tangents at $x=\pm a$ occur when
$$
x^2 = \frac{4C}{4AC - B^2}.
$$

(Note that the conditions on $A,$ $B,$ and $C$ guarantee that 
$\frac{4A}{4AC - B^2} > 0$ and $\frac{4C}{4AC - B^2} > 0.$)
Set
$$
\frac{4C}{4AC - B^2} = a^2, \quad
\frac{4A}{4AC - B^2} = b^2.
$$

It follows that $C=A a^2/b^2.$ Using this to substitute for $C$
in one of the equations above and solving for $B,$ we get
$$B = \pm\sqrt{ \frac{ 4A(a^2A - 1)}{b^2}}.$$

It follows that $a^2A - 1\geq 0,$ that is, $A \geq \frac1{a^2}.$
If $A = \frac1{a^2}$ then $B = 0$ and $C = \frac1{b^2},$
that is, we get the equation of the inscribed ellipse whose axes are aligned with the coordinate axes.
For any other value of $A$ we get an ellipse whose axes are inclined;
the direction of inclination depends on whether we choose the positive
or negative.
For very large values of $A$ the major axis of the ellipse is very
nearly the diagonal of the rectangle.